Aligning equal signs and brackets at the same time
I wish to have the following

.
This is the code to generate the image above.
\begin{align*}
    \vec{a}\dvec{B} = \vec{a}(\vec{b}\wedge\vec{c}) \\
    \vec{a}(\vec{b}\wedge\vec{c}) = (a_x\hx + a_y\hy + a_z\hz)\big[&(b_y c_z - b_z c_y)\hy\hz \\
    + & (b_z c_x - b_x c_z)\hz\hx \\
    + & (b_x c_y - b_y c_x)\hx\hy\big]
\end{align*}

However, how can I align the first equation equal sign with the second one, but maintaining the alignment of the yz, zx and xy terms?
Edit #1:
Below follows what my preamble looks like and some of the definitions used in my document.
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\hx}{\hat{x}}
\newcommand{\hy}{\hat{y}}
\newcommand{\hz}{\hat{z}}

\newcommand{\dvec}[1]{\overset{\Rightarrow}{#1}}
\newcommand{\tvec}[1]{\overset{\Rrightarrow}{#1}}

As for the errors my document is currently producing: there are no errors. What I am mainly seeking is a way to align the first equation with the second one without losing the alignment done inside the square brackets part.

Please include code that begins with \documentclass, includes all relevant packages and definitions, ends with \end{document} and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Since the equation is not numbered, I'd use aligned for the bracket alignment. Remember to use \begin{aligned}[t] if you've never used the construct before

@SandyG the document is pretty big, that's why I only included the part that really matters. As for the preamble, I have updated the question to include what I am currently using.

@daleif thank you! I have already tried the aligned environment but it did not work too. I get a blank space after the square bracket, which makes sense since the environment is aligning the bounding box with the rest of the equation.

Off-topic: amsfonts is loaded automatically by amssymb, and amsmath is loaded automatically by mathtools. Hence, no need to load amsfonts and amsmath explicitly.

Show your code.

@Octonions "the document is pretty big, that's why I only included the part that really matters." We don't want to see your whole document. Make a small, but compilable test file that allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class and a document environment so people don't have to puzzle together your code fragments.

You want to use gather and a nested alignedat with three points of alignment.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\hx}{\hat{x}}
\newcommand{\hy}{\hat{y}}
\newcommand{\hz}{\hat{z}}

\newcommand{\dvec}[1]{\overset{\Rightarrow}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\vec{a}\dvec{B} = \vec{a}(\vec{b}\wedge\vec{c}\,) \\
\begin{alignedat}{3}
\vec{a}(\vec{b}\wedge\vec{c}\,) = (a_x\hx + a_y\hy + a_z\hz)\bigl[
      & (b_y c_z &&- b_z c_y&&)\hy\hz \\
{}+{} & (b_z c_x &&- b_x c_z&&)\hz\hx \\
{}+{} & (b_x c_y &&- b_y c_x&&)\hx\hy\bigr]
\end{alignedat}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}


The terms in parentheses (coefficients in the wedge product) aren't the same width, so I decided to place the differences at the closing parenthesis.
A zoom on the relevant part with guide rules:

Avoid \big and use \bigl or \bigr for, respectively, opening and closing delimiters.
Note also the \, when a \vec{...} is followed by a ).
Possibly simpler with IEEEeqnarray:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\newcommand{\hx}{\hat{x}}
\newcommand{\hy}{\hat{y}}
\newcommand{\hz}{\hat{z}}

\newcommand{\dvec}[1]{\overset{\Rightarrow}{#1}}
\newcommand{\tvec}[1]{\overset{\Rrightarrow}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rlCll}
\IEEEeqnarraymulticol{5}{c}{\vec{a}\dvec{B} = \vec{a}(\vec{b}\wedge\vec{c}\,)} \\
\vec{a}(\vec{b}\wedge\vec{c}\,) = (a_x\hx + a_y\hy + a_z\hz)\bigl[
      (&b_y c_z &-& b_z c_y&)\hy\hz \\
{}+{} (&b_z c_x &-& b_x c_z&)\hz\hx \\
{}+{} (&b_x c_y &-& b_y c_x&)\hx\hy\bigr]
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}

\end{document}


If you want the main = signs aligned, you shouldn't repeat \vec{a}(\vec{b}\wedge\vec{c}):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\newcommand{\hx}{\hat{x}}
\newcommand{\hy}{\hat{y}}
\newcommand{\hz}{\hat{z}}

\newcommand{\dvec}[1]{\overset{\Rightarrow}{#1}}
\newcommand{\tvec}[1]{\overset{\Rrightarrow}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\vec{a}\dvec{B} 
  &= \vec{a}(\vec{b}\wedge\vec{c}\,) \\
  &= \begin{alignedat}[t]{3}
     (a_x\hx + a_y\hy + a_z\hz)\bigl[
      & (b_y c_z &&- b_z c_y&&)\hy\hz \\
{}+{} & (b_z c_x &&- b_x c_z&&)\hz\hx \\
{}+{} & (b_x c_y &&- b_y c_x&&)\hx\hy\bigr]
\end{alignedat}
\end{align*}


\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCrllll}
\vec{a}\dvec{B}
  &=& \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{5}{l}{\vec{a}(\vec{b}\wedge\vec{c}\,)} \\
  &=& (a_x\hx + a_y\hy + a_z\hz)\bigl[
      (&b_y c_z &-& b_z c_y&)\hy\hz \\
&&{}+ (&b_z c_x &-& b_x c_z&)\hz\hx \\
&&{}+ (&b_x c_y &-& b_y c_x&)\hx\hy\bigr]
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}

\end{document}



I think (but am actually not 100% certain about this...) the OP also wants to align the = symbols in rows 1 and 2.

@Mico Added the change

(I updated this answer after receiving additional information from the OP.)

how can I align the first equation = sign with the second one, but maintain the alignment of the yz, zx and xy terms [in rows 2 thru 4]

I think that the upper half of the following screenshot accomplishes your formatting objective. Note the care I took to assure that TeX treats the + symbols at the starts of rows 3 and 4 as binary rather than as unary operators.
However, I'd recommend taking a different approach, one that places the second equation across just two rows instead of across three.
Both approaches embed an aligned[t] environment inside an align* environment.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathllap macro; load 'amsmath' automatically
\newcommand{\dvec}[1]{\overset{\Rightarrow}{#1}} % per the OP's addendum

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \vec{a}\dvec{B} 
      &= \vec{a}(\vec{b}\wedge\vec{c}) \\
    \vec{a}(\vec{b}\wedge\vec{c}) 
      &= 
    \bigl(a_x\hat{x} + a_y\hat{y} + a_z\hat{z}\bigr) 
    \begin{aligned}[t] 
        \bigl[  
                     &(b_y c_z - b_z c_y)\hat{y}\hat{z} \\
     \mathllap{{}+{}}&(b_z c_x - b_x c_z)\hat{z}\hat{x} \\
     \mathllap{{}+{}}&(b_x c_y - b_y c_x)\hat{x}\hat{y}
        \bigr]
    \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

%% 2nd, alternative approach
\begin{align*}
    \vec{a}\dvec{B} 
    &= \vec{a}(\vec{b}\wedge\vec{c} \mkern1.5mu ) \\[\jot] 
         % insert half a \thinspace between '\vec{c}' and `)`
    \vec{a}(\vec{b}\wedge\vec{c} \mkern1.5mu ) 
    &= (a_x\hat{x} + a_y\hat{y} + a_z\hat{z})\\ 
    &\quad\times\bigl[
          (b_y c_z - b_z c_y)\hat{y}\hat{z} 
         +(b_z c_x - b_x c_z)\hat{z}\hat{x} 
         +(b_x c_y - b_y c_x)\hat{x}\hat{y}
         \bigr]
\end{align*}

\end{document}


Hey! Thank you for taking your time to read and come up with the code! In fact, the lower half is what I am trying to achieve. I only want the upper half to be shifted to the left so it can align with the equal sign of the second equation. I have also edited my question to include the preamble and also the definitions for the additional commands.

@Octonions - You're welcome. Please see the updates I applied to my answer.
